# What does this notation mean: $\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \dots$

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, notation, limsup-and-liminf

In Cohn's measure theory, second edition, p166, there is written:

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then the upper derivate $(\overline{D}\mu)(x)$ of $\mu$ at $x$ is defined by

$$(\overline{D}\mu)(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\sup \left\{\frac{\mu(C)}{\lambda(C)}: C \in \mathcal{C}, x \in C, e(C) < \epsilon\right\}$$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is the set of all cubes in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $e(C)$ denotes the length of a side of a cube.

Can someone explain what the notation $(\overline{D}\mu)(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\sup \left\{\frac{\mu(C)}{\lambda(C)}: C \in \mathcal{C}, x \in C, e(C) < \epsilon\right\}$ means?

I am only familiar with $\limsup$ of sequences, for example $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = \inf_{n} \sup_{k \geq n} x_k$

Comment: What happens to the number $\dfrac {\mu(C)}{\lambda (C)}$ when $\epsilon$ change ?

Comment: See [Limit superior and limit inferior : Real-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Real-valued_functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they really mean the $\limsup$? To me, it looks more like one is supposed to take the supremum of the set and then pass to the limit, as it says $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\sup$ and not $\limsup_{\epsilon\to0}$.

In very small steps: Look at the set
$$ A_\epsilon:= \left\{\frac{\mu(C)}{\lambda(C)}: C \in \mathcal{C}, x \in C, e(C) < \epsilon\right\}, $$
take its supremum
$$ S_\epsilon:= \sup A_\epsilon \in\mathbb [0,\infty],$$
and then pass to the limit
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}S_\epsilon, $$
which has to exist in $[0,\infty]$, as by the definition of $A_\epsilon$, the quantity $S_\epsilon$ is decreasing for $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: Thank you. I figured this was the interpretation, but your answer also tells why it exists in $[0, +\infty]$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you maybe tell what $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} a_\epsilon$ means when the terms $a_epsilon$ are in the extended real numbers $[-\infty, + \infty]$?I know the definition when $a_\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, but that definition does not work if the terms become infinity .

Comment: Since $S_\epsilon$ is decreasing for $\epsilon\to 0$, there are only two cases: Either $S_\epsilon=\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$, in which case the limit it also $\infty$; or there is some $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $S_\epsilon<\infty$ for all $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$, in which case we are essentially dealing with a real sequence.

Comment: Thanks! And isn't there a more general definition that would work in general (if we dropped the decreasing thingy).

Comment: You can in fact use the same definitions as in the usual real case, where you would also declare $a_n\to\infty$ iff for every $K\in(0,\infty)$ there is some $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n|>K$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: But this is limit of sequence? Not of function.

Comment: You mean that the index is discrete? Well, $\lim_{x\to y}a(x)=a$ is just short for $\lim_{n\to\infty}a(x_n)=a$ for all sequences $(x_n)$ converging to $y$. You can apply this to what I wrote above.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I will think about it. Thanks for your excellent responses!

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The limsup of a family of sets $D_\epsilon$ is defined as
$$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0+} D_\epsilon = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}\bigcup_{\epsilon' < \epsilon} D_\epsilon.$$
This can be thought of as the set of the elements $x$ such that whatever $\epsilon_0 > 0$, there exists a $\epsilon$ such that $x \in D_\epsilon$ or the elements that are in infinitely many $D_\epsilon, \epsilon < \epsilon_0$ for any $\epsilon_0 >0$ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the text I'm reading, the function $\overline{D} \mu$ is $[0, +\infty]$ valued, so no set as result. I'll keep looking for another interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

This Community Wiki answer (I'll add more to it later) can be used to make a list of places where suitable definitions of $\limsup$ can be found. (It would also be a good idea to include the relevant parts of at least some of the texts.)

---

D. J. H. Garling, *A Course in Mathematical Analysis*, Vol. I (Cambridge University Press 2013), p.150f.

---

J. M. Hyslop, *Real Variable* (Oliver & Boyd 1960), p.107f.

---

Brian S. Thomson, Judith B. Bruckner & Andrew M. Bruckner, [Elementary Real Analysis: DRIPPED Version](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/) (2008):

> **5.3 Limits Superior and Inferior**
>
> If limits fail to exist we need not abandon all hope of discussing
>   the limiting behavior. We saw this situation in our study of
>   sequence limits in Section 2.13. Even if $\{s_n\}$ diverges so that
>   $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$ fails to exist, it is possible that the two
>   extreme limits
>   $$
> \liminf_{n\to\infty}s_n \text{ and } \limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n
> $$
>   provide some meaningful information. These two concepts always exist
>   (possibly as $\infty$ or $-\infty$). A similar situation occurs for
>   functions. The theory is nearly identical in many respects.
>
> **Definition 5.26: (Lim Sup and Lim Inf)**
>   Let $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with domain $E$ and
>   suppose that $x_0$ is a point of accumulation of $E$. Then we write
>   $$
> \limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \inf_{\delta>0}\sup
> \{f(x) : x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta), \ x \ne x_0\}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \sup_{\delta>0}\inf
> \{f(x) : x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta), \ x \ne x_0\}
> $$
>   As this section is for more advanced readers we have left the
>   development of this concept to the exercises. [...]

The book is freely downloadable. It may have been updated since I downloaded it.
The definition needs to be adapted to the case of a one-sided limit as $\epsilon\to0$: this is exercise **5.3.6** in the book.

Comment: *%$^&£! **&%, I've been downvoted! Why? I don't know why I bother, sometimes, I really don't.

Comment: I upvoted. Don't let anonymous trolls discourage you! Thanks for your effort!